# PostgreSQL - dblink_exec statement_timeout

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have a function that used dblink_exec inside. Sometimes this execution takes a long time and in some cases produces deadlocks.
I know that I can set local lock_timeout and local statement_timeout but when I do this inside a function, It doesn't take any effect over dblink_exec.

Is that any way to set those parameters on dblink_connect? I know that I can set these two parameters on .conf file but I want to do this locally (per connection).

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Julio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite ugly, but you can specify the statement timeout (to be implemented on the remote side) in the connection string, using the `options` construct.

```
create or replace function dblink_timeout() returns int language plpgsql as $$ 
  declare xx int;  
begin 
  select x into xx from 
    dblink(
      'dbname=jjanes options = ''-c statement_timeout=500 -c lock_timeout=100''',
      'select count(*) from pgbench_accounts'
    ) as (x int);
  return xx; 
end 
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But one more thing: Is that any way to set lock_wait parameter in this connection string ?